# Foreach not supporting when the result set has one record in logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have to read data from an XML and load it to SQL. So in middle I need to add some business logic for each record for which I used for each task in Logic Apps. But when there is a single record in the XML, result is being considered as Object rather than array and logic app fails

This is how my XML looks:

```
<VDSP_INPUT_A_Set><VDSP_INPUT_A_Record><head><blanket_number>CMC741311</blanket_number></head></VDSP_INPUT_A_Record></VDSP_INPUT_A_Set>
```

ForEach logic: `VDSP_INPUT_A_Set.VDSP_INPUT_A_Record`

Foreach loop needs to executed even if there is one record in XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue, I did some research. I convert the xml to json, while there is only one record under , the result json will be {key/value pair} but not [array]. So if we fill in For each with this value, the action will fail. I think this issue caused by design.

For a workaround, I think we can add a specific record under , for example:

```
<VDSP_INPUT_A_Set>
    <VDSP_INPUT_A_Record>
        <head>
            <blanket_number>CMC741311</blanket_number>
        </head>
        <head>
            <blanket_number>specific_test</blanket_number>
        </head>
    </VDSP_INPUT_A_Record>
</VDSP_INPUT_A_Set>
```

And then add a condition(If) action in For each action to determine if it is equal to "specific_test".

If true: do insert sql

If false: do nothing